# click button to open and display another js file

Tags: button, titanium

Trying to get my nxbutton to open andra display another JSfile(cat.js). 
Ive looked at threads that has the same problem and tried many different solutions and this is what ive ended up with, and it doesnt work.

http://pastie.org/8686848#9

cat.js is in the resource folder.

Wat do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working in app.js then try this

```
nxbutton.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
  var catwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'cat.js',
    title: 'Cat Window',
  });
  catwin.open();
});
```

otherwise

```
nxbutton.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
  var catwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'cat.js',
    title: 'Cat Window',
  });
  Ti.UI.currentWindow.open( catwin );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Alloy, try this code, otherwise Adnan code is fine

```
nxbutton.addEventListener('click', function(e) ) {
    var catWin = Alloy.createController('catwin').getView();
    catWin.open();
}
```